# Flutter - How to print all the contents of a large Uint8List?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `Uint8List` whose size is 15000 bytes. I need to check its contents. When I try to use `print()` for this, it prints only the first part of the list and then `<...>`.

Is there a way to print the whole Uint8List in console?

Comment: For Flutter, use [`debugPrint`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/DebugPrintCallback.html).

Answer (score 0):

use `log(yourUnit8List)`, note that there is a `log` from `dart:developer` & `dart:math`, you need the `dart:developer` `import 'dart:developer';` also, it does not print in the `terminal`, it prints in `run` tab

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should convert it to string, right? `log(myList.toString());`. Where is the `run` tab in VS Code? I have `Terminal` and `Output` tabs. I see the output of log in none of them.

Comment: @Salahuddin try running your app in debug mode and check the ' Debug Console' section.